# Vuetify: Datatable is stacking new entries at the bottom -- how can I reverse that?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify's datatable and all new entries a customer makes are put at the bottom.  Is there a way I can reverse that order so that the newest entries are at the top without having to click the sort button?

**template**

```
    <v-data-table
         :headers="headers"
         :items="orders"
         :items-per-page="15"
         class="elevation-1"
     ></v-data-table>
```

**script**

```
    export default {
        name: 'DataTableComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                headers: [
                  { text: 'Order Id', align: 'left', value: 'order_id'},
                  { text: 'Customer', value: 'customer' },
                  { text: 'Order Total', value: 'total', sortable: false},
                  { text: 'Date', value: 'date' },
                ],
                orders: this.$store.getters.getOrders
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can try sorting your `getOrders`

Comment: that did it -- thanks @KarmaBlackshaw

Comment: Any reason why not do the sorting at server side API call?

Comment: very much welcome @burtonLowel

Comment: if you are adding new entries by using `push` to the state, you may try `unshift`, as `push` adds the entry to end of the array, `upshift` adds it to the top of the array.